# How to call web service in the presence of iBeacon on iOS 10

Tags: swift3, apple-push-notifications, ios10, ibeacon

I need to call a web service when the user enters the iBeacon region.
Can I achieve this with iOS 10 notification service extension?
Or How we can connect the iBeacon with server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UNNotificationServiceExtension` class is designed to customize **remote notifications** and beacon initiated notifications are local, so this class is not useful for the purposes you describe.

To send a message to a server on beacon detection, you simply put the code to call the service in the `didRangeBeacons` callback.

The `URLSession` class is often used to make these calls.   Here is a tutorial for using that: https://grokswift.com/simple-rest-with-swift/

Comment: Using this "didRangeBeacons" can I call web service even Application not in Background?

Comment: If you combine it with beacon monitoring, yes.  Once the first beacon in a CLBeaconRegion is detected, iOS will auto launch you app into the background and let it run for about 10 seconds.  This gives enough time to make a web service call if the server is responsive.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Should I need to turn on background mode or something? I believe we can not debug using developer profile.

Comment: No background modes are needed for this to work, and you can test with a developer profile.   Although it is always tricky to test background launching, but it can be done.